# Select dropdown needs to display details of providers when selected - cant get url to appear through my script

Tags: javascript, html

I will appreciate any form of insight as to how to get this working.
When I select a provider from the drop down menu I wish for the relevant information to show below.

I am trying to get the details for StudyP to show like this:

Heart of Worcestershire college - with url attached
Emily Leleu
01905 743587

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<label for="programSelect">  Please choose a Programme<br><br></label>
<select id="nearestStore">
  <option value="noSelection">Please Select</option>
  <option value="StudyP">Study Programmes</option>
  <option value="Train">Traineeships</option>
  <option value="Acc">Accountancy</option>
  <option value="Agri">Agricultural and Land Based</option>
  <option value="Anim">Animal Care</option>
  <option value="Beauty">Beauty Therapy</option>
  <option value="Busin">Business Improvement Tech</option>
  <option value="Busina">Business Administration</option>
  <option value="CallC">Call Centres</option>
  <option value="Creative">Creative arts</option>
  <option value="Construct">Construction</option>
  <option value="Customer">Customer service</option>
  <option value="Cyber">Cyber Security</option>
  <option value="Early">Early years ChildCare & Education</option>
  <option value="Electro">ElectroTechnical</option>
  <option value="Electric">Electricity Industry</option>
</select>


<div id="phoneNumber"></div>

<script>
  var nearestStore = document.getElementById("nearestStore"),
      phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber"),

      contactdetails = {
        noSelection: "",
        StudyP: "<br><a href="http://www.howcollege.ac.uk">Heart of       Worcestershire College</a><br>Emily Leleu<br>01905 743587",

      }

   nearestStore.onchange = function(){
    phoneNumber.innerHTML = contactdetails[this.value];
  }



  </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with the quotes:

```
StudyP: "<br><a href="http://www.howcollege.ac.uk">Heart of       Worcestershire College</a><br>Emily Leleu<br>01905 743587"
```

Should be:

```
StudyP: "<br><a href='http://www.howcollege.ac.uk'>Heart of       Worcestershire College</a><br>Emily Leleu<br>01905 743587"
```

## EDIT Based on user comment request

If you want to add some more text you can concatenate it:

```
contactdetails.StudyP += 'Some more text';
contactdetails.StudyP += 'Yet some more text.';
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for correcting that simple error, its been a long past 24 hours :(

Comment: If I wanted to add another 3 lines to the same variable(another provider, how is that possible? I tried but it now shows blank! :(

Comment: Thankyou taxicala for your fast response and taking the time to help.

Comment: Thankyou taxicala for your fast response and taking the time to help.

Comment: I need to stop pressing enter for double response :(
When I try to concatenate as shown above, it results in blank, perhaps I am putting it in the wrong place :(

Comment: I have tried putting it underneath the existing variable and with the end of script function, also replacing the ' with "

Comment: I must be doing something horribly wrong. I am still unable to get it working.